# Problem with print and then delete a document

Tags: c#, printing

I have many image JPG that I need to print and then delete them.
The Print method is this:

```
 public void PrintJPG()
    {

       PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();            
       for (int i = 0; i < this.PathsJPG.Length; i++)
       {
          currentpath = getCurrentPath(i);
          pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
          pd.Print();                
       }               

    }

    public static void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(currentpath);
        Rectangle m = e.MarginBounds;

        if ((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height > (double)m.Width / (double)m.Height) // 
        {
            m.Height = (int)((double)i.Height / (double)i.Width * (double)m.Width);
        }
        else
        {
            m.Width = (int)((double)i.Width / (double)i.Height * (double)m.Height);
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, m);
    }
```

The delete method is this:

```
public void DeleteGenerateDoc()
    {
        FileInfo file; 
        foreach( string path in JpgPath)
        {
            file = new FileInfo(path);
            file.Delete();
        }            
    }
```

And the Main is this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] PathJPG = array with path of the jpg files  // here is a function that return a array of jpg paths

        PrintJPG();          

        DeleteGenerateDoc();
    }
```

The problem is I must wait to complete the print and then delete the document. What I must add in my code for the program to wait for printing to finish and then delete the jpg file?

Comment: I don't see Async or parllel in here anywhere, and this code is inherently synchronous. Have you tested if it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Yes, if I do only print the code work and if I do only delete the code work.

Comment: Your code isn't completel and your main doesn't path the reference of a jpg array anywhere. It's also in local scope. Have you tested the this code right here?

Comment: In my main I have a function who return Array oj jpg. string[] PathJPG = getJpgFIle() - this is the code that I tested, but I don't want to write that method here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [PrintDocument.Print()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print?view=netframework-4.7.2) method only sends the document to the printer queue. It doesn't wait for it to actually print.

But you can use the [PrintDocument.EndPrint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.endprint?view=netframework-4.7.2) event to get notified when the page has been printed. You could use the notification to delete each file after it has been printed. This was my earlier suggestion.

However, if your program only performs this task and then exits it still wouldn't work. In this case you need to halt execution until it's done. This is a bit more tricky but should be possible by using a [CountdownEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

In your case it might look something like this:

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
CountdownEvent countdown = new CountdownEvent(this.PathsJPG.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < this.PathsJPG.Length; i++) {
    currentpath = getCurrentPath(i);
    pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
    pd.EndPrint += (o,e) => { countdown.Signal(); }
    pd.Print();
}
countdown.Wait();
```

The last line should block your program until all pages has been printed. After this you should be able to delete the files.

Comment: I try this, but same error. He doesn't know when printer is finish with the page.